# Integration measures, subtraction and absolute value

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We know that the definition of integration measure states that 
1) $\tilde{\mu}(I_A) = \mu(A)$
2) $\tilde{\mu}(aA+bB) = a\mu(A) + b\mu(B)$

Is it true that $\tilde{\mu}(I_A - I_B) = \tilde{\mu}(I_A) - \tilde{\mu}(I_B) = \mu(A) - \mu(B)$? Would this still hold if it was absolute $|I_A - I_B|$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int (I_A-I_B)=\int I_A -\int I_B$ holds if either $\mu (A) <\infty$ or $\mu (B) \infty$. If both measures are infinity then  $\mu (A)-\mu(B)$ is not even defined. I is not true that $\int |I_A-I_B|=|\int I_A -\int I_B|$. In fact $\int |I_A-I_B|=\int I_{A\setminus B} +\int I_{B\setminus A}$.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please clarify why the last equal sign is true?

Comment: @Ubanstan Verify that $|I_A-I_B| =I_C$ where $C=(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A) $ . Then integrate.

Comment: @Ubanstan take an point $x$ and consider the four cases: $x\notin A\cup B$, $x \in A \cap B$, $x\in A, x\notin B$ and $x\in B, x\notin A$.

Comment: Oh...I over-complicated it. Thank you, Kavi.